# Entropy of Mixing Derivation

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, ideal-gas

In Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics 2nd Edition, Callen states that the Entropy of a mixture of ideal gases is given by (3.39)

$$S = \sum_j N_js_{j0} + \left(\sum_j N_jc_j\right)Rln\frac{T}{T_0} + \sum_jN_jRln\left(\frac{V}{N_jv_0}\right)$$

He then states that we can re-write it as follows (3.40)

$$S = \sum_j N_js_{j0} + \left(\sum_j N_jc_j\right)Rln\frac{T}{T_0} + NRln\frac{V}{Nv_0} - R\sum_j N_jln\frac{N_j}{N}$$

where the last term represents the Entropy of mixing. However I cannot see how he got from Eqn(3.39) to Eqn(3.40). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard rules of logarithms
$$
\ln \left(\frac{V}{v_0 N_j}\right) = \ln \left(\frac{V}{v_0 N}\frac{N}{N_j}\right) = \ln \frac{V}{Nv_0} - \ln \frac{N_j}{N}\;.
$$
Using that $N = \sum_j N_j$ then gives the desired result